# Fastlane doesn't upgrade bundle id correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fastlane

We are using fastlane to deploy our iOS App to fabric. This app has two different app identifiers for different environments.

```
update_app_identifier(
  xcodeproj: 'app.xcodeproj',
  plist_path: './app/Info.plist',
  app_identifier: bundleIdentifier
)
ipa = gym(
  scheme: 'app',
  export_method: 'enterprise',
  project: 'app.xcodeproj',
  output_name: "app.ipa"
)
```

`bundleIdentifier` variable is passed though method arg.

iOS project is uploaded to repo with `project.pbxproj` with the first app identifier (`com.test.example1`), and we try to deploy to fabric it all goes great. `fastlane beta` fills the identifier with that one.

If we try to deploy with `fastlane live`, it tries to generate a version with `com.test.example2`. After finishing the build phase and trying to sign it, it throws this:

```
error: exportArchive: Provisioning profile "match InHouse com.test.example2" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.

Error Domain=IDEProfileQualificationErrorDomain Code=8 "Provisioning profile "match InHouse com.test.example2" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement." UserInfo={IDEProfileQualificationError_Profile=<DTDKProvisioningProfile www: UUID: wwwwww, name: match InHouse com.test.example2, team: w12w12, platform: iOS>, NSLocalizedDescription=Provisioning profile "match InHouse com.test.example2" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.}
```

Looking at the `pbxproj` file I've seen that app identifier for `com.test.example1` still remains there. It doesn't seem to change, and I think that's the problem about entitlements.

Anyone with the same problem?

thanks!